# C#/Java - Consuming WCF Service from Android emulator

Tags: c#, java, android, wcf, web-services

I'm trying to learn how Android interacts with WCF (C#) service. I have gone through a lot of posts regarding the same, here at SO. However, I couldn't find a definite answer to the problem. Every body has posted their own approach and it is confusing me.

I have created a demo service which just returns the string "Hello World!!".

```
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return ("Hello World!");
    }
```

I have defined the service contract as:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, 
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetMessage")]
    string HelloWorld();
```

The service is working fine on `http://localhost:32444/Service1.svc`.

Now, from Android I'm trying to consume the service with the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */

    private final static String SERVICE_URI = "http://10.0.2.2:32444/Service1.svc";
    TextView textView;
    Button btnShow;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);

        btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0){

                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URI + "/GetMessage");

                    request.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
                    request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

                    HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
                    String output = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), output, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    textView.setText(output);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                }
        });
    }
}
```

The emulator shows no output. I checked using Toast message and the return is null.The error is due to "HTTP1.1/400 Bad Request", which I came across while debugging.

Can somebody please guide me with this? Also, if the approach/concept is wrong please point to me my mistake and provide an explanation.

Thanking all in advance!

From the WCF Service Library:
Service1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace WcfServiceAndroid
{
    /* NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name 
     * "Service1" in both code and config file together.*/
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return ("Hello World!");
        }

        //public string[] NumberWorld()
        //{
        //    string[] arr= {"1","2","3","4","5"};
        //    return arr;
        //}

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
}
```

IService1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace WcfServiceAndroid
{
    /* NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name 
    "IService1" in both code and config file together.*/
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        //[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetMessage", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
          //      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal)]
        [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "/GetMessage")]
        string HelloWorld();

        //[OperationContract]
        //string[] NumberWorld();

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }

    // Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations
    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBindingAndroid"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceAndroid.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceAndroid.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://<domain>:<port>/WcfServiceAndroid/Android/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

From the Service application:
Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Service1.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceAndroid.Service1"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing

```
http://localhost:32444/Service1.svc/GetMessage
```

from browser and check whether it is working.

Comment: No, http://localhost:32444/Service1.svc/GetMessage doesn't work. What can I do about it?

Comment: Since its a rest based service, you are supposed to get the result in browser right? Otherwise it might be a problem with your service.

Comment: Do you think you can help me out with that Eldhose? I updated the original post with the service/interface classes and the config files. Kindly check once. Thanks.

Comment: Go through this tutorial in creating a Rest based WCF service. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services.    It seems like problem with your service.

Answer (score 0):

try to grub wsdl information and build client across generated classes. find tools like "svcutils" for java. 
Addditional you can make an error with connection setting and authentification.

Answer (score 0):

instead of localhost you should use 10.0.2.2 . Because localhost is not your computer. It is your android emulator. And if you still can't connect, try to edit your iis config.

in your  user Documents > IISExpress > applicationhost.config  edit your wcf service projects binding information. it is something like this : bindingInformation="*:21422:localhost"
and you should delete localhost and should be something like this : bindingInformation="*:21422:"

to be clear your connection address is http:// 10.0.2.2:port/svcfile/...

I hope it works

edit: you have to run visual studio with administrator privileges (Run as administrator)