# Android Not Connecting to WCF service which works in the browser

Tags: java, c#, android, web-services, wcf

I have a **WCF Service** (working tried it in the browser) the code for it

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "Login/?username={username}&password={password}")]
    bool Login(string username, string password);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "Search/?query={query}&type={type}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<AndroidBook> Search(string query, int type);
```

**EDIT:** the web config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="??????.AndroidBridge">
        <endpoint address="" binding ="webHttpBinding" contract="??????.IAndroidBridge" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="webHttpBinding"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and when testing it in browser i get the following:

```
{"LoginResult":true}
```

which is true but when trying to connect in the android client  with this code:

```
try {
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(urls));
                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                            out.close();
                            String responseString = out.toString();
                            //..more logic
                        } else{
                            //Closes the connection.
                            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("HTTP GET:", e.toString());
                    }
```

i got an exception of `filenotfound` or when i get a response with outer codes i got a `bad request` , i have googled this problem and came across same problems and read the following articles
[C#/Java - Consuming WCF Service from Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20212848/c-java-consuming-wcf-service-from-android-emulator)
[Exposing a service running on localhost to an Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20066625/exposing-a-service-running-on-localhost-to-an-android-emulator)
[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception?lq=1)
and using fiddler i got the correct response in **JSON**
any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: have you used asynctask or a thread for network operation in android?

Comment: @IllegalArgument i read about `asynctask` but for testing purposes i have put the following in android code `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); ` do you think that this is the reason for my problem ?

Comment: Explain your setup. Webserver? Where? On pc? On web? Using devices or emulator?

Comment: i have the server running on localhost pc using VS2013 on Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: You did not tell your complete setup. Though I asked for specific settings. Further question: do you request internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @greenapps if i get you correctly i have the website on an **IISEXPRESS** running on localhost:33829 with not deployed on the web

Comment: Yes but i had more questions. Please answer.

Comment: @greenapps absolutely i have the permission in  the manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: Please reread my first comment and answer all. I still do not know your setup.

Comment: @greenapps please specify what you need to know because i used both ways device and emulator that's way i didn't answer it

Comment: @Mhd i have the same problem you do and almost the same setup of the webserver please help

Comment: @YaserJaradeh bro i am sad :(

Comment: If you use an emulator, then on witch pc is the emulator?